# Android L with ADT

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

How can i start to test Android L with ADT(eclipse) latest version.
I 'm not sure , most of people say can test Android L with Android Studio.
I want to know it is OK Android L with eclipse(latest version and sdk).

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

Comment: You have to use a certain type of phone or tablet to test on

Comment: I have system image downloaded to test with Emulator..